# Amazon Connect - Using CustomerEndpoint.Address as a callback number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am trying to build a call flow where I offer CustomerEndpoint.Address to be a callback number in case they are disconnected from the agent. Connect seems able to read back my cellphone number when i call in, but I'm wondering what would happen if someone calls who has caller id blocked, or if there is some other circumstance where CustomerEndpoint.Address might not exist.

Is CustomerEndpoint.Address always present with the expected telephone number of the caller? If not, are there tips on how to build a flow that first asks if the caller's number can be used as a callback number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bullseye answer from AWS support: If the caller id is blocked for any reason (carrier, or customer hid their number etc), CustomerEndpoint.Address will be "anonymous".

You can check this value using Check Customer Attributes against System -> Stored Customer Number. I pipe "anonymous" and No Match directly to a Store Customer Input which prompts to enter a callback number. If the Stored Customer Number starts with "+", I read it back to the customer and ask if it's a good callback number.